# Kivy Buildozer "ImportError: No module named docopt"

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I finished developing my Kivy app and now I want to package it to run on Mac OS X. I'm following [these instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html) from the Kivy docs. Unfortunately I am running into some trouble:

**Environment**

- Mac OS X 10.10.5
- Kivy 1.9.1 @ /Applications/kivy.app (Python3 version
  of Kivy)
- Python 3.5.1 via Homebrew

**Install Buildozer**

```
sudo pip3.5 install buildozer
```

**Build Kivy App for Mac OS X**

```
cd /my/app
buildozer init
buildozer osx debug
```

**Results**

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory .buildozer
# Create directory bin
# Create directory /my/app/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory .buildozer/osx/platform
# Create directory .buildozer/osx/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for osx
# Check if kivy-sdk-packager exists
# kivy-sdk-packager does not exist, clone it
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127    0   127    0     0    200      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   200
100  191k    0  191k    0     0   187k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1019k
Archive:  master.zip
c013d00bbaca6ff8ef6c806d0f1d148c9c0c1b39
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/.gitignore  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/LICENSE  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/README.md  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/__init__.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/appveyor.yml  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/README.md  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/changelog  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/compat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/control  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/copyright  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/kivy-doc.docs  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/kivy-examples.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/kivy-tools.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python-kivy-bin.install  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python-kivy-common.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python-kivy.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python3-kivy-bin.install  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python3-kivy-common.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/python3-kivy.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/daily/rules  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/changelog  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/compat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/control  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/copyright  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/kivy-doc.docs  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/kivy-examples.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/kivy-tools.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python-kivy-bin.install  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python-kivy-common.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python-kivy.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python3-kivy-bin.install  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python3-kivy-common.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/python3-kivy.install  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/linux/debian/stable/rules  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/README.md  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/cleanup_app.sh  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/create-osx-bundle.sh  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/create-osx-dmg.sh  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/MakeSymlinks  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/background.png  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/icon.icns  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/link_duplicate.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/data/script  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/package_app.py  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/__init__.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/common.py  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/README.txt  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/kivy-bash.bat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/kivy.bat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/kivybash.rc  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/kivyenv.sh  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/kivywineenv.sh  
   creating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/cython.bat  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/easy_install.bat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/link_msysgit.bat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/make-portable-python.py  
 extracting: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/pip.bat  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/data/tools/register-python.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/dropbox.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/gdrive.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/glew.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/gstreamer.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/kivy_win_sdk.py  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/readme  
  inflating: kivy-sdk-packager-master/win/sdl2.py  
# check if Kivy.app exists in local dir
# Kivy.app found at /Applications/Kivy.app
# copying it to platform dir
# Install platform
# Check application requirements
# Remove directory and subdirectory /my/app/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /my/app/.buildozer/applibs
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Build the application #1
# Copy application source from /my/app
# Create directory /my/app/.buildozer/osx/app
# Copy /my/app/main.py
# Copy /my/app/minu.kv
# Package the application
# Building package
# Create minu.app

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_app.py", line 45, in <module>
    from docopt import docopt
ImportError: No module named docopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 987, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 234, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 250, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 198, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 155, in build_package
    check_output(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 711, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'package_app.py', '/my/app/.buildozer/osx/app', '--appname=minu', '--bundlename=MinU', '--bundleid=org.test', '--bundleversion=0.1', '--displayname=MinU']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

As far as I know, my Kivy app does not require `docopt` so I'm not sure why Buildozer is complaining about it. What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. So, `package_app.py` is written in Python2. As a result, it needed these modules installed in the system Python2:

```
pip2 install docopt sh
```

Now Buildozer is happy, and I am too.

On a side note, to reduce the size of my app, I trimmed the fat off before packaging. Specifically, I removed `gstreamer` from `myapp/.buildozer/osx/platform/kivy-sdk-packager-master/osx/Kivy.app/Contents/Frameworks`. That eliminated ~190 MB of fat. Yum :)

Answer (score 1):

You may:

1. Delete the line

   from docopt import docopt
2. Just put docopt.py next to your package_app.py

Comment: thanks but commenting out `from docopt import docopt` in `package_app.py` and placing `docopt.py` in the same directory results in this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_app.py", line 232, in <module>
    arguments = docopt(__doc__, version='package app {}'.format(__version__))
NameError: name 'docopt' is not defined`

Comment: I ment that you would do one of the 2... not both at once :)